# Nginx and Jekyll: serving in a subdomain

Tags: nginx, jekyll

I'm currently stuck in configuring Jekyll and nginx to work together on a VPS. 
Essentially, I set up everything and a git hook from my local machine to the VPS.

Here is my nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server_ip;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_ip/blog;

    location / {
    root /var/www/blog;
    index index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Ideally, what I'd like is to serve what is in `/var/www/blog` at `blog.domain.example`, or `blog.server_ip` at the moment.

However, when `jekyll build` runs, the URLs are all wrong. I can see `index.html` at `server_ip/blog`, but the `/blog/` bit in the URL is not replicated in the links on the Jekyll page.

For example, a post should live at `server_ip/blog/2015/04/07/title`, but the URL I'm given is `server_ip/2015/04/07/title`. Same goes for the CSS files, and images as well.

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `baseurl: "/blog"`

And link to posts like this `<a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{post.url}}>...`.

And generaly use `{{site.baseurl}}` to built any url.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful. Is there a difference between setting `{{ site.baseurl }}` and just appending `"/blog"` to `{{ site.url }}`?

Comment: `site.url` is the `protocol//domain` and is only useful for feed.xml to compose full urls. Anywhere else, we just need relative urls, then we just use `site.baseurl`.

Comment: That makes an awful lot of sense. I was asking in the hope not to have to go through dozens of articles to replace links (to images in particular). @david-jacquel